# WebSocket in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, websocket

today my problem is that I am developing an app that is using a WebSocket. On iOS everything is working out fine but on android the WebView doesn't support the WebSocket. Whats the fastest/most elegant way to solve this problem?

**[edit]**

As this post is viewed quite often I want to share some possible solutions.

**Solutions:**

1. Java Websocket Client Implementation & JavaScript Interface
2. PHP Websocket Client Implementation & making a background (i.e. jQuery GET) request to the  PHP-script *(worked for me as I wanted to send only one line of message.)*

**Android Websocket Libraries**

3. http://autobahn.ws/
4. http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht

**Someone had the same issue and descriped how he worked around**

5. http://chpeck.tumblr.com/post/37273036645/socket-io-with-android-webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android webview doesn't accommodate WebSocket. So you need to implement with some WebSocket library.

jWebSocket 
http://jwebsocket.org/

weberknecht
http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht/

Comment: What if I want to go it without chaning the HTML/JS Source. What do you think of overriding the JS-WebSocket Object by an JavaScript Interface?

Answer (score 4):

I created a sample project which adds the WebSocket object to the WebView for phonegap. You can find it here:
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-phonegap-android

I put up a video going over the project here:
http://blog.pusher.com/2012/7/5/pusher-on-phonegap-for-android

I used this project to demonstrate how to use PhoneGap with [Pusher](http://pusher.com) on Android but ultimately it's just a project that happens to include the Pusher script tag. **You could easily use another library that needs the `WebSocket` object** or just use it directly.

It uses the websocket-android-phonegap library:
https://github.com/anismiles/websocket-android-phonegap

Comment: Do you include your PhoneGap App in an Android WebView or just opened in the Android Browser?

Comment: The sample project creates a PhoneGap app which uses Android WebView with an injected `WebSocket` object. This means you can then use `WebSocket` within the JavaScript code running in the Android WebView.

Comment: Yes. You write your code in JavaScript and it uses the injected `WebSocket` object which proxies the calls between the JavaScript and  Java wrappers. You can use the project and code nothing other than HTML, JavaScript & CSS. Try it out and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Can I also use HTML5 geolocation in this WebView? For instance, I want to track users of the app in real time using geolocation.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the WebView is an instance of the stock Internet browser app. So, if it supports geolocation then yes, you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

check your error code first;if the code is :ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED;
Try to add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to you application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml like below:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```