# Websockets in phonegap with an app that uses socket.io

Tags: node.js, cordova, websocket, socket.io

We are working on a phonegap app and are using node.js in combination with socket.io. We know that websockets aren't supported by phonegap yet, but that there are some ways to make them work (https://github.com/anismiles/websocket-android-phonegap and http://anismiles.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/websocket-support-in-android%E2%80%99s-phonegap-apps/)

Only problem is that these examples make them work by overwriting things that normally socket.io takes care of for you.

My question: Is there any way to use websockets in phonegap when your app uses socket.io?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to use websockets in phonegap when your app uses socket.io?

Yes. There is a similar question here about generic WebSockets in Phonegap. My answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13527585/39904

This project example I link to in my example uses the [Pusher](http://pusher.com) JavaScript library, but you could substitute that for the socket.io library very easily.

For quick reference, here's the sample project: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-phonegap-android

Comment: I got it working for the first login page, but it seems to fallback on xhr-polling as soon as we change page. Cordova cannot seem to find the Websockets constructor. We use require.js and knockout with sammy.js also in our app.

Any tips on getting that part working?

Comment: I found it myself, I looked all functions up from DroidGap and found onNewIntent(Intent intent). I just added this line to the function: this.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebSocketFactory(this), "WebSocketFactory"); 

Which adds a the listener everytime something new happens to the page!