# Websocket does not work in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, websocket

What should I do in order to use websocket in my ionic app?
I couldn't find any info in docs about this.

I'm just writing in my code:

```
.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.planets = [{'name': 'Меркурий', 'order': '1'},
                    {'name': 'Венера', 'order': '2'},
                    {'name': 'Земля', 'order': '3'},
                    {'name': 'Марс', 'order': '4'},
                    {'name': 'Юпитер', 'order': '5'},
                    {'name': 'Сатурн', 'order': '6'},
                    {'name': 'Уран', 'order': '7'},
                    {'name': 'Нептун', 'order': '8'},
                    {'name': 'Плутон', 'order': '9'},
                   ];

  $scope.sendData = function(selected) {
      var planets = $scope.planets;
      var num;
      for (var i=0; i < planets.length; i++) {
          if (planets[i].name === selected) {
              num = planets[i].order;
          } 
      }

      var socket = new WebSocket("ws://somesource.com");
      socket.send(num);
      socket.onmessage = function(data) {
          alert(data);
      };

  };

})
```

And nothing...

By design somesource.com must return me some data responding on my "num".

Answer (score 2):

It's likely you would have found something if you had searched for WebSockets on Cordova instead of Ionic ([Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) is an underlying component of Ionic).

WebSockets are not officially supported because Android has no native WebSocket support and only the newest iOS devices have native WebSocket support:

[WebSockets or an alternative with phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482954/websockets-or-an-alternative-with-phonegap)

https://www.quora.com/Does-PhoneGap-support-WebSocket

As an alternative, I recommend following this tutorial to learn how to use [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) with Ionic:

https://www.sitepoint.com/using-socket-io-and-cordova-to-create-a-real-time-chat-app/