# Webview blank page quakenet

Tags: android, webview

Before read my post, I try to search, but I didn't resolve my problem.

I use a webview for QuakeNet IRC WebChat

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://webchat.quakenet.org/");
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

I have a blankscreen. 
But when I try to load http://www.google.com, that's work.

I have try to enable JS, but it's not this.

Can you help me pls.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chat on the website seems to use websockets.

According to this post: [WebSocket in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507438/websocket-in-android-webview) websockets are not supported natively on android webview.

Check your logcat for errors.

You can try to follow this link and change your code http://foretribe.blogspot.it/2013/08/how-to-make-android-webview-support.html